# Disable reflection between Google Drive and Drive folder

Tags: google-drive

I recently installed Google Drive in my Windows 8 Pro and there is a folder for Google Drive. Is it possible to delete files in Drive folder without getting it deleted from the Drive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with Google Drive, no. It essentially seems to act like a mirror and updates whenever there are changes (both local & remotely), if you delete a document from your local system and try to access it through Google Docs you will get the message in the screen shot below, so it is possible to recover files through this method (assuming you have access permission) as files seem to go into a "bin" which seems similar to a recycling bin or something of the sort.

[image: Google Docs screenshot]

Comment: btw: screenshot in on OSX, but I don't think that should have had any effect on the outcome of this